# muuri drag-and-drop doesn't work on Safari Mac

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, grid

When you drag one of the "cards" it just stays where you drop it - it doesn't replace the dragged-over cell and then snap into place.  Here's a simple pen (written by someone else) that works fine on Chrome and Firefox - but doesn't work on Mac Safari.  https://codepen.io/bobglass53/pen/XQQdQL

```
const grid = new Muuri(".grid", {
   dragEnabled: true
});
```

Just confirmed that it works fine when using Muuri@0.4.0 - so this is a "recently" introduced issue.

Answer (score 2):

Needed to add a web animations polyfill.  Working fine now.